# Replace in notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have many line with the structure:

```
start...ABC...
```

In notepad++, how to replace `ABC` in all the lines start by `start` by another string (for example `DEF`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex would be:

Find what: `^(start.*)ABC`

Replace with: `$1DEF`

`^` - tells that regex should start at the start of the line and `$1` will match whatever matched in first group, which is `(start.*)`